# How to make value returned by ajax global

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have an ajax function that returns a value from a django function.
I want to make the output global so that i can use it in a select dropdown..
here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{ 
  function AjaxCall(HandleData) 
  {
    return $.ajax({
    url: "/evidence_values/",
    type: "post",
    data: {'evidence':document.getElementById('evidence').value},
    success: function(data){ HandleData(data);}
                   });
  }

    $("#save").click(function(){
       AjaxCall(function(output){filter_data = output});
                               });

    function CallAjax(DataHandle) 
    {
     return $.ajax({
                  url: "/get_evidence_items/",
                  type: "post",
                  success: function(data){DataHandle(data);}
                  });
    }

    $("#evidence_selected").click(function(){
       CallAjax(function(output){items_data = output});
                                             });
```

and the dropdown elsewhere in index.html

```
<select name="evidence_selected" id="evidence_selected" style="margin-right:20px;color:#5c89db;margin-top:20px;margin-left:40px;height: 2em;border-radius: 3px;">

<option value="selectedvidence" id="selectedvidence"name="selectedvidence">Select Evidence Number</option>

{% for item in items %}
<option value="{{item.evidence}}">{{ item.evidence }}</option>
{% endfor %}
<option id="new"value="new">New</option>

</select>
```

Comment: If you have a variable in global scope, then you can write to it in the `success` functions you have defined. However, it is probably a better idea to use `success` to call an "update" function that rewrites the values in the select. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You could have your handle data function insert options [into the select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript)

```
  $("#evidence_selected").append('<option value=1>' + dataStr + '</option>');
```

Or, store the values in an [array:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861859/add-to-array-jquery)

```
 var evidenceArray = [];
 evidenceArray.push(dataStr);
```

And then create [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366616/foreach-object-array-in-jquery) from array:

```
$("#evidence_selected").empty();
$.each(evidenceArray , function() 
{
  $("#evidence_selected").append('<option value=1>' + this+ '</option>');
});
```

But if you are populating on ajax success I'm not sure why you would use a for-each and not insert?

Comment: Hi Stefan, that displays ["123","45566","wrtt","4466"] instead of displaying an item one by one downwards